# Add if condition on array length directly in Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my Handlebars template, I want to enable/disable a button based on "selectedRows" array length (i.e. enable if selectedRows > 0 and disable it otherwise i.e. on array length 0)
I want to avoid introducing any extra instance variable in the component JS. Is it possible to do this directly in handlebars ?

i.e. something like below

```
{{my-button count=selectedRows enabled=(if selectedRows > 0)}}
```

enabled is boolean (true/.false)

Answer (score 5):

If you install the widely-used [Ember Truth Helpers addon](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers), you could have something like this:

```
{{my-button count=selectedRows enabled=(gt selectedRows 0)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is just checking if length is greater than `0`, you could do,
(assuming `selectedRows` is a `Number`),

```
{{my-button count=selectedRows enabled=(if selectedRows true false)}}
```

Since JS considers 0 a falsy value, you could use it as the condition.